# Proving the Fibonacci Recurrence

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Following is out homework problem. And I have no clue how to do it. The strong induction one seems doable, but a is a nightmare. I have done all sorts of weird things over the past week, including somehow reaching a conclusion that the sum of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers is linked to the sum of the binomial coefficients at a certain power (haven't worked out the exact relationship but there's definitely something there).In short, I've done a lot, just not actually solving the problem. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: This does look really very straightforward. Is it (a) or (b) you are having trouble with?

Comment: Having trouble with a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT for (a): You need to use an induction hypothesis that is stronger than the obvious one.

> $P(n)$: For all $c,d\in\Bbb R$, $f(n;c,d)=f(n-1;c,d)+f(n-2;c,d)$.

In the induction step you’ll apply this induction hypothesis with $c=b$ and $d=a+b$.

Comment: I could maybe do it with Strong Induction but doesn't that conflict with b?

Comment: @pasha: You don’t need strong induction; it’s ordinary induction that uses a very short calculation.

Comment: I'm sorry I've tried with this newer hypothesis but I still end up at the same problem. I don't see a way to do it without reducing to base cases, which gets me an LHS expression in Fibonacci terms and RHS in Binomial Coefficient terms

Comment: @pasha: Assume $P(n)$. Then $$\begin{align*}f(n+1;c,d)&=f(n;d,c+d)\\&=f(n-1;d,c+d)+f(n-2;d,c+d)\\&=f(n;c,d)+f(n-1;c,d)\,.\end{align*}$$ The middle equality uses the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Thank you

Comment: @pasha: It can be hard to get out of a blind alley; you're welcome.